# Does using .css() of jQuery override pseudo class in CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-class

I wonder why when using `.css()` function, it overrides the pseudo class in CSS, like `:hover` for example. Shouldn't it only affect the normal condition of the element, not the `:hover` one ? or am i doing something incorrectly ?

Here's an example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>  
  <head>
    <style>
      #test {
        background : red;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        opacity : 0.2;
      }

      #test:hover {
        opacity:1.0;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $('#test').css('opacity', '0.5');
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="test"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the page loads, i get the div with only `opacity = 0.5`, for both normal and `:hover`.
Shouldn't it be `0.5` for normal and `1.0` for `:hover` ?

My question is how to prevent this from happening ?

Comment: `.css()` edits the elements inline styles, thus, overriding your pre-defined CSS.

Comment: Remove javascript and add opacity 0.5 in test and then check the page it works fine as you want....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.css()` applies *inline* styles to the selected element(s), and as per the rules of *cascading* styles inline styles have a higher priority than the styles in your stylesheet.

You can make the class in the stylesheet more important than the inline style as follows:

```
 #test:hover {
     opacity:1.0 !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do what you're trying to do is NOT to set the value of opacity, but instead use addClass(), removeClass(), or toggleClass() to make any changes.